# Multiple Drupal pagerer module

Tags: drupal, pager

I have installed [Drupal pagerer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer) on my site (Drupal 7).

It works fine when I have one pagerer loaded on my page. But as I have a lot of categories on my page, Drupal load 4 pagerer, and only one is functional. I need to reload page so I can use other one on same page. Is there any way to make them all works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the additional pagerers because you are using views, you need to set the ID on each pager in the views settings. The middle column of the views edit window has a section for Pager, there are two links there the first sets the pager type, and the second the pager settings. The ID for the pagers is available after you click settings.